# Chord Graph with Holoviews: Troubles concerning adding colors and labels

Tags: python, holoviews, chord

I've tried to plot a chord graph according to http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html#elements-bokeh-gallery-chord
Nonetheless, I'm receiving a graph lacking labels and colors, which is totally different from the picture shown on the website:
[image]

The following is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
from bokeh.sampledata.les_mis import data

hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size=200)

links = pd.DataFrame(data['links'])
nodes = hv.Dataset(pd.DataFrame(data['nodes']), 'index')

chord = hv.Chord((links, nodes)).select(value=(5, None))
chord.opts(opts.Chord(labels='name', 
                       cmap='Category20', 
                       edge_cmap='Category20', 
                    node_color=dim('name').str()))


mr = hv.renderer('matplotlib')
mr.show(chord)
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: The last two lines ars suspicious. You are changing your renderer to `matplotlib`, which causes a kind of a reset of your ploting options. Remove those two lines and your code is indentical to the code on [Chord tutorial](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html#elements-bokeh-gallery-chord). This normally should work.

Comment: @mosc9575 Thank you for your reply. However, with out the two lines, the picture  won't even show. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please describe your environment? Do you work with Jupyter Notebook? Do you get an output if you run a different example of HoloViews? Check your installation of HoloViews and the dependencies of this library. If necessary try to update HoloViews to the latest version. This may solve your problem.